# Passing arbitrary random number distributions to a function

Tags: c++, variables, random, std

I am writing a matrix initialization method that fills a matrix of type T with random numbers of type T from a random number distribution that the user can choose. The section of my implementation file would look something like

```
// file name: Matrix.h
#include <random>

typedef std::default_random_engine rnd_eng;

template<class T, int N, int M>
class Matrix{
  private:
    /* private members here */
  public:
    Matrix<T, N, M>();
    /* other constructors */
    ~/Matrix<T, N, M>();

    void init_all(T value); // initializes all elements of Matrix NxM to value
    void init_Random(rnd_eng, USER RANDOM NUMBER DISTRIBUTION HERE);
};

/*
  Ideally I would have something that looks like the following in a main.cpp file
    rnd_eng engine(1);
    std::uniform_real_distribution real_dist(1.0f, 1.0f);
    std::uniform_int_distribution int_dist(1, 9);

    Matrix<float, 32, 64> my_mat_a;
    Matrix<int, 128, 256> my_mat_b;

    my_mat_a.init_Random(engine, real_dist);
    my_mat_b.init_Random(engine, int_dist);
*/
```

I would like to know what would go in place of "USER RANDOM NUMBER DISTRIBUTION HERE". Do you guys have any suggestions? Apologies if this is a basic question.

** Edit: made my question a bit clearer hopefully

Comment: Well, what exactly IS the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is a function that accepts multiple different underlying types of objects (generators) that share a common signature, but no hierarchy.

This is a problem most easily solved with templates:

```cpp
template<class T, int N, int M>
class Matrix{
    ...
    template <typename RandomNumberDistribution>
    void init_Random(rnd_eng, RandomNumberDistribution& dist);
    ...
};
```

By making this a `template`, `init_Random` can operate with any input for distribution.

This will give you the desired syntax of:

```cpp
    rnd_eng engine(1);
    std::uniform_real_distribution real_dist(1.0f, 1.0f);
    std::uniform_int_distribution int_dist(1, 9);

    Matrix<float, 32, 64> my_mat_a;
    Matrix<int, 128, 256> my_mat_b;

    // calls template with RandomNumberDistribution = std::uniform_real_distribution 
    my_mat_a.init_Random(engine, real_dist); 
    // calls template with RandomNumberDistribution = std::uniform_int_distribution 
    my_mat_b.init_Random(engine, int_dist);
```

The inputs can also be constrained further to only work with distributions either by using SFINAE ([c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11),[c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14),[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)), or `concept`s ([c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)). This would ensure that calling `init_Random` with something that does not work will not be considered for overload resolution.

### SFINAE approach

[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) introduced `std::is_invocable_r` which can be used in conjunction with `std::enable_if` to only enable this overload if `dist` is properly invocable and returns a type convertible to `T`:

```cpp
    template <typename RandomNumberDistribution,
              typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r_v<T,RandomNumberDistribution,rnd_eng&>>>
    void init_Random(rnd_eng, RandomNumberDistribution& dist)
```

Using `is_invocable_r` can be used to test that the input `RandomNumberDistribution` must be invocable from `rnd_eng&`and return a type convertible to your matrix's underlying type, `T`. The `enable_if` will ensure that this function is only callable by any input where `RandomNumberDistribution` can be called.

If you're below [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), you will need to implement a custom `is_invocable_r` trait, or used an off-the-shelf one from an open-source library -- but this is still compatible with earlier C++ versions.

### Concepts approach

If you're in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)'s or above, you could constrain this with concepts. There is a [`std::invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) concept, but not an `invocable_with_result` -- so you would have to make one yourself:

```cpp
template<typename R, typename F, typename... Args>
concept invocable_with_result =
  requires(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    static_cast<R>(std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  };
```

Which then just requires setting up the requirement on the function `template`:

```cpp
    template <typename RandomNumberDistribution>
        requires(invocable_with_result<T, RandomNumberDistribution, rnd_eng&>)
    void init_Random(rnd_eng, RandomNumberDistribution& dist)
```

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer which I believe addresses everything I wanted. Thank you very much. I am going to learn a lot from this.